# How do I use JOSN code to turn a Request Date text to RED when the request is greater that 5 days in a SharePoint list

Tags: json, sharepoint, conditional-formatting

I have the following in my column format, however the text does not turn red

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-
```

formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
"color": "=if([$Request_x0020_Date] >= @now + 432000000, '#ff0000', '')"
}
}

I have data in my list form 7/15, which is greater than 5 days and items from today. If I change the less than, greater than symbols I can get the text to turn red, but it turns it all red.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, below JSON code works well on my end.

```
  {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
    formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if([$RequestDate] >= @now + 432000000, '#ff0000', '')"
    }
  }
```

[image]

Pay attention to column variation `$Request_x0020_Date` in your code, you have to use the internal name of the column after "$". You can get the internal name of the column via List settings -> Columns section -> Click the column name to edit. You can find the internal name from the URL. For example, "RequestDate" after "Field=" is the internal name of my column "Request Date".
[image]